# Can't flip sprite using Mobile Input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, mobile, sprite

I am currently working on porting my original project from PC version to mobile, I need help flipping sprite whenever I move left using mobile input, and flip right when I move right. Please help, im losing my mind, i'm sure it's easy but im missing something. I cant find a place to put my Flip() function

My code right now for movement using mobile input.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private Rigidbody2D myRB;

    private Vector2 moveAmount;
    private Animator myAnim;
    private bool facingRight = true;

    public Joystick joystick;


    private void Start()
    {
        myAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        myRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }


    private void Update()
    {
        Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(joystick.Horizontal, joystick.Vertical);
        moveAmount = moveInput.normalized * speed;

        if (moveInput != Vector2.zero)
        {
            myAnim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        }
        else 
        {
            myAnim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        myRB.MovePosition(myRB.position + moveAmount * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

    void Flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
        Scaler.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = Scaler;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea if your `Flip` method will do as you expect but logic-wise you can just call `Flip` if the horizontal direction doesn't match the facing:

```
private void Update()
{
    Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(joystick.Horizontal, joystick.Vertical);
    moveAmount = moveInput.normalized * speed;

    if (moveInput != Vector2.zero)
    {
        myAnim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
    }
    else 
    {
        myAnim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
    }

    if ( (facingRight && moveAmount.x < 0) 
      || (!facingRight && moveAmount.x > 0))
    {
        Flip();
    }
}
```

Comment: Holy moly, thanks dude!
I totally forgot about moveAmount.x yikes


Perfectly works now :)

Comment: Glad I could help! Consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359) my answer!

Comment: I did dude :)
I have one question for you aswell, so basically I want to move on the input on the left and shoot at the any screen point, and shooting works but when i move i also shoot, can you help me fix that? Like disable shooting while you are moving or something

Comment: Thanks! Something like `if (moveInput == Vector2.zero && /* whatever shoot input expression you already have*/) { /* shoot */ }` ?

Comment: Ahh, no, I can't explain it, do you have discord or anything so I can send you screenshot what I mean?

When I hold left side of my screan my joystick input controller i can move fine, but it also constantly is shooting at my fingers position, I want it to shoot when it detects second finger press for example on the other side of the screen.

Comment: @IgorGrba You might want to [ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) ;) then you can post your screnshots and code there. Plus if I can't figure it out, maybe someone with more mobile experience than I have can see it :)

Answer (score 0):

i shall refer you to an answer that seems to be adequate for your question:

https://answers.unity.com/questions/952558/how-to-flip-sprite-horizontally-in-unity-2d.html

In code, you would just assign true/false to SpriteRenderer.flipX and .flipY.
Answer from JoeStrout

Comment: Problem is, my character is made up of various body parts, it's not a single game object with spriterenderer, so this method doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I think calling Flip() in update and passing horizontal value should work because it ranges from -1 to 1.